# LibreOffice Writer: How to ensure all tables have the same width?

Tags: libreoffice

I have an RTF file with 3 tables. The upprmost table and lowermost table were created with Microsoft Word some time ago but when I've added a new table between the two I saw it is discrepant with the other two around it.

I've painted red boxes to visualize the discrepancy I mean to:

[image]

### My question:

I only aim that all 3 tables will have the exact same width.

How could I set all tables to have the exact same width without the discrepancy I just described?

I ask this because I didn't find a way as available in Microsoft Word: "Set table width to maximal in relation to margin length".

### Update - file to test

Here is a file with two tables (link omitted). The first table is the one originated in Microsoft Word (2016), and the second one originated in LO Writer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under *Table -> Properties* there is a *Width* setting.  Change all three tables to use the same value.

You could also make adjustments under the *Column* tab.

**EDIT**:

With the example file, under *Table -> Properties* for the first table, change *Width* to `6 "` and *Spacing / Left* to `0.00 "`.

[image: aligned tables]

Comment: Sadly changing either of these  (table-width/column-width/remaining space, etc) as the same, doesn't help. I even tried to clear formatting but still there's the same discrepancy.

Comment: What I did in the end was to create 3 empty tables with their LibreOffice defaults and migrate all data to there. The original problem I encountered seems like a bug.

Comment: Your approach sounds like a good one. Start with a clean slate rather than trying to fix the original tables.

Comment: I hope you are not sarcastic. I would generally try to fix a problem and not start from scratch. In this case I tried to fix them myself, consult here, and re-fix them, but nothing helped. I reviewed and got to the conclusion it's a bug or a serious User Interface problem which I have no spare time to deal with so I'll just comment here that given the circumstances I started from scratch.

Comment: *"I hope you are not sarcastic."* No, I thought your idea was a good one.  Sorry to hear you are not happy with it.

Comment: I am happy with my idea.

Comment: If you post a link to a sample file then we may be able to offer better answers.  Also, there are more experts at https://ask.libreoffice.org.

Comment: Well I no longer have the exact file but I've uploaded a file with a similar problem (the first table in it is originated from Microsoft Word) in case you want to check it.

Comment: @JohnDoea: See edited answer.